# Trying to get a int variable number to equal a string

Tags: c

I need some help, I've been trying to get this code to work and I can't for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong Please help Basically what i have to do is simulate a deck of cards. I know what I have to do basically for everything except getting these faces to match up. and have the program run. I've been wracking my brains for a few days and I need help. Please help me

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

enum faces{Ace = 0, Jack = 10, Queen, King};
char * facecheck(int d); 


int main() 
{ 
    int deck[52], i, n;
    char suits[4][9] = 
    {
         "Hearts",
         "Diamonds",
         "Clubs",
         "Spades"};


    n = 0;

    for(i = 0; i<52; i++)
    {
          deck[i] = n;
          n++;
          };



    for(i=0; i<52; i++)
    {
             printf("%2d of %s \n", i%13, suits[i/13]);
             if(i%13 == 0 || i%13 == 10 || i%13 == 11 || i%13 == 12)
             printf("%s \n ", facecheck(i) );
             };


    return 0; 
}  

char * facecheck(int d)
{
     static char * face[] = 
     {
            "Ace",
            "Jack",
            "Queen",
            "King" };

           if(d == Ace) 
           return face[0];
           else
           {
               if(d == Jack) 
               return face[1];
               else
               {
                   if(d == Queen)
                   return face[2];
                   else 
                   { 
                        if(d == King)
                        return face[3];
                   }
               }
           }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with it? Which part? What info did you get from debugging? What did you try to fix? Also, you don't need a `;` at the end of every loop

Answer (score 1):

`facecheck()` acts gracefully when the input is one of four valid and handled values, namely 0, 10, 11, and 12.

But, the caller is passing the entire range [0, 52) as input.

```
for(i=0; i<52; i++)
printf("%s \n ", facecheck(i) );
```

That is the source of the problem.

I think the function `facecheck()` can be enhanced to do something (e.g. assert or print an error) for invalid inputs.

Comment: Your assumption is wrong. What value is `Jack`? Hint: It's not `1`.

Comment: @Zeta: Thanks! I realized that, with the last edit I made it explicit.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

enum faces{Ace = 0, Jack = 10, Queen, King};
char * facecheck(int d); 


int main() 
{ 
    int deck[52], i, n;
    char suits[4][9] = 
    {
        "Hearts",
        "Diamonds",
        "Clubs",
        "Spades"};


    n = 0;

    for(i = 0; i<52; i++)
    {
        deck[i] = n;
        n++;
    };



    for(i=0; i<52; i++)
    {       
        if(i%13 == 0 || i%13 == 10 || i%13 == 11 || i%13 == 12)
            printf("%s ", facecheck(i%13) );
        else printf("%d ", i%13+1);
        printf("of %s \n", suits[i/13]);
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0; 
}  

char * facecheck(int d)
{
    static char * face[] = 
    {
        "Ace",
        "Jack",
        "Queen",
        "King" };

    if(d == Ace)
        return face[0];
    else
    {
        if(d == Jack) 
            return face[1];
        else
        {
            if(d == Queen)
                return face[2];
            else 
            { 
                if(d == King)
                    return face[3];
            }
        }
    }
}
```